# Installing OpenCV as php extension under Windows

Tags: php, windows, opencv

Could please anyone recommend me a guide/tutorial on how to install OpenCV as
php extension under Windows ?

Comment: Afaik OpenCV is not a PHP extension library. Do you mean the FaceDetect Extension for OpenCV?

Comment: yes i mean FaceDetect Extension for OpenCV.

Answer (score 4):

My approach is compiling an executable from C code that uses OpenCV library then you can execute your program with [Exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.

If you are looking for a pure Php solution, check [this](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP/tree/master).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/ is a very good tutorial if you know a little about PHP & Apache Web Server.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: In that website there was instructions to install it in Linux or Unix operating system. But how can I install it in my Windows operating system?

Comment: Please let me know if you have achieved it on windows.

Comment: I found the compiled dll here http://code.google.com/p/pecl-win/downloads/list let me know if it works for you