# how to install php-opencv in windows OS?

Tags: php, windows, opencv, installation

Can anyone please help me on how to install php-opencv (https://github.com/hihozhou/php-opencv) in the windows operating system. I have installed php 7 and opencv 3.3 that are prerequisites for php-opencv.

Please help me with the installation steps or any ideas on how to install.

I couldn't find the windows installation help in http://phpopencv.org/zh-cn/docs/install.html

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please, [read how to ask good questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and try to shape your question accordingly. You should provide some code, show us some effort - we can help you and you will understand it more clearly, if you do your homework first in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is a community that helps coders and developers who has struck into an issue and needs experts help to resolve it. Its not a Q and A forum.

Coming to your issue, I hope you need to install opencv with PHP in windows platform. Assuming this is correct, you can check the [OpenCV-for-PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP) for examples. This is a PHP extension wrapping the OpenCV library for image processing. It lets you use the OpenCV library for image recognition and modification tasks.

You can also check these threads for more information
[Installing OpenCV as php extension under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470820/installing-opencv-as-php-extension-under-windows)

[Is there any way to integrate OpenCV with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002895/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-opencv-with-php)

Also please make sure in future, try something and post it in stackoverflow along with the issues you are facing.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion as this is my first post. Actually I am looking to install https://github.com/hihozhou/php-opencv

Comment: You want to install that github package?

Comment: Yes, I want to install that github package in windows OS.